# get target file size by symlink on cifs share

Tags: linux, symlink, samba, cifs

in shared directory *f:/dir* on Win2008 absolute symlink created
with

```
mklink f:/dir/symlink2file f:/dir/file
```

This share then mounted in Debian with

```
mount -t cifs -o file_mode=0600,user=login,pass=passwd //host/share /mountpoint
```

And file */mountpoint/symlink2file* is not recognized as symbolic link, so I can't get size of target file.

mount output:

```
#mount
//host/share on /mountpoint type cifs (rw,relatime,sec=ntlm,unc=\\192.168.0.40\share,username=login,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.40,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,rsize=65535,wsize=65536,actimeo=1,user=login)
```

stat output:

```
#stat -L /mountpoint/symlink2file

  File: `/mountpoint/symlink2file'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 16384  regular empty file
Device: 12h/18d Inode: 3659174697239319  Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-01-26 14:34:44.491487300 +0600
Modify: 2016-01-26 14:34:44.491487300 +0600
Change: 2016-01-26 14:45:06.012178900 +0600
 Birth: -
```

So two questions.
What should I do to follow symlink and get target file size on mounted CIFS share?
Why 'nounix' presented in mount output and how to get rid of it in mount options?

Comment: Deleted - error

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks With absolute paths does not work on a cifs share. Try to remake them using relative paths. (e.g. in your case:

```
cd f:\dir
mklink file2symlink file
```